# how to add a DelegatingHandler to all HttpClients in .Net 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0

Lots of questions around this subject, so I hope this is not a duplicate.  Here's two similar code samples :

```
builder.Services.ConfigureAll<HttpClientFactoryOptions>(options =>
{
    options.HttpMessageHandlerBuilderActions.Add(builder =>
    {
        builder.AdditionalHandlers.Add(new MyNiceHandler());
    });
});
```

And another

```
builder.Services.ConfigureAll<HttpClientFactoryOptions>(options =>
{
    options.HttpMessageHandlerBuilderActions.Add(b =>
    {
        b.PrimaryHandler = new MyNiceHandler();
    });
});
```

All I'm doing in the Handler is setting standard elements in the URLs. I can't find documentation describing the difference between Primary Handler and 'Additional Handler', and I'de like to know.

Comment: Your question body is completely different to its title. Please edit one or the other to clarify.

Comment: Hi @Mike, `PrimaryHandler` represents the main` HttpMessageHandler` in the chain, responsible for processing the HTTP request and response.
`AdditionalHandlers` represents additional `HttpMessageHandlers` added to the chain, which execute **after the primary handler** and can intercept or modify the request/response.